# Select Values in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible to do something like the following in BigQuery to quickly generate sample input?

```
SELECT * FROM values ('david',10), ('tom',20)
```

Or does it only accept the verbose `SELECT ... UNION ALL ...` format:

```
select 'david' name, 10 age union all select 'tom', 20;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider below as an option

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('david' as name,10 as age), 
    ('tom', 20),
    ('jon', 30)
  ])
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>
    ('david',10), ('tom', 20), ('jon', 30)
  ])
```

both give you quick dummy data to play with

[image]

Comment: cool, yea the second approach is easy enough to remember I think I'll use that -- thanks!

Comment: This is super helpful but note to reader: it doesn't work if you just have a single column. Add a second dummy column and you'll be fine. :)