Emulating VALUES in GoogleSQL?
Is the following the closest, least verbose way to emulate a VALUES clause in BigQuery?
WITH Roster AS
 (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('Adams' as LastName, 50 as SchoolID),
   ('Buchanan', 52),
   ('Coolidge', 52),
   ('Davis', 51),
   ('Eisenhower', 77)
])) SELECT * FROM Roster

The old way I was doing and what Google uses in their docs is something like:
WITH Roster AS
 (SELECT 'Adams' as LastName, 50 as SchoolID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Buchanan', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Coolidge', 52 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Davis', 51 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Eisenhower', 77)
SELECT * FROM Roster

In Postgres or something I'd do:
WITH Roster(LastName, SchoolID) AS (
    VALUES('Adams', 50),
   ('Buchanan', 52),
   ('Coolidge', 52),
   ('Davis', 51),
   ('Eisenhower', 77)
) SELECT * FROM Roster

Which is quite similar to the first approach.

Yes and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715211/select-values-in-bigquery

That's exactly right! Using UNNEST is a great approach for creating sample data. It's more efficient than using multiple UNION ALL statements, especially when dealing with larger datasets. UNNEST treats the entire array as a single operation, whereas UNION ALL would process each row individually.
Here are some helpful resources to learn more about other BigQuery techniques:

Get query performance insights

Optimize query computation

Change in select query response for GoogleSQL Vs Legacy SQL


